# UIImagePickerViewController with UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera orientation issue

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimagepickercontroller

Just interested, if anyone has any sample code, using the UIImagePicker for a cameraview in fullscreen with landscape/portrait rotations.

Instead of

```
[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:NO];
```

I'm adding the imagepicker.view as a sub View like so:

```
[cameraView addSubview: imagePicker.view];
```

The problem is, when this happens, the frame of the imagePicker.view is being added with a 90 degrees rotation. Which would be fine to perform an affine Translation, except doing so changes the rotation of the actual Camera feed.

Doing something like, works fine,

```
[imagePicker.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
```

until the user rotates.

I can listen for the rotate notification with this:

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification
```

But applying a Affine Translation, is ruining the camera overlay and it's subviews.

Comment: Yea the resolution was to not use the Image picker, instead just simply use AVCamera, I can post the general code used here if you like? There's already a lot of good sample code out there however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outcome was that using the UIImagePicker for the modal camera popup isn't appropriate for more than basic AVCamera usage. I still used it for picking existing photos, but ended up using the sample code

My main VC header keeps:

```
UIImagePickerController *_imagePicker;
AVCameraView *avCameraView;
```

AVCameraView retains:

```
@property (retain) CaptureSessionManager *captureManager;
```

Which is used to take photos as well as swap between the front/back camera if the device is  a 4+
https://github.com/mrdavenz/CaptureSessionManager